# Best practices sharing types across multiple Haskell packages/microservices

Tags: haskell, architecture, microservices

I am working in a Haskell project that is composed of multiple microservices. There are certain types that are needed by multiple services at the same time and therefore are defined in separate libraries that are imported by whichever needs them (each type is versioned). But there are things about it that make me uncomfortable and I was wondering which are the best practises regarding that topic. In particular:

- I don't know how to handle instances of shared types. In order to avoid orphans the instances must be defined in the type's module for each of the types. But then there are instances that are not needed by all the microservices that import the package and have to be included regardless, potentially adding redundant dependencies to the microservice. An example would be a datatype **T** that is shared by a frontend and a backend. It has an instance of **Store** in order to be stored in a database that is not needed by the frontend, but still makes the frontend depend of the store package.
- In order to avoid the previous issue I could introduce a wrapper every time the type has to "leave" a microservice to represent that type going through the wire. In the previous example I would have a **Storable T** which would have an instance for **Store**. This adds quite a lot of overhead to the overall development process though.
- Is it even a good idea to share the types or should each microservice define its own representation of each type, so nothing has to be shared? So for a type **T** a microservice **MA** would have a representation **A.T** and an instance to serialise it in order to send the data to a microservice **B** which would decode that data into a representation **MB.T**.

And finally, regarding the logistical side of the matter,

- What's the most convenient way to structure the project? Would a monorepo be a better choice than having separate repos/submodules?
- Maybe related to the previous one, is there any way to find out automatically which microservices should be redeployed when one of the shared libraries is modified because the changes in the library affect a piece of code that is being used by the microservice?

Comment: If you have two services that share types, then those two types are coupled to each other. Then what's the point of making them microservices? Why not define each as a separate module, and compose them both into a single executable? In that way, the compiler will tell you whether or not the two modules can communicate with each other.

Comment: Hmm - e.g. for communication purposes, IMO it makes sense to have one "definition of truth" (type definitions and their serializer/deserializer code), possibly coupling multiple services. One service creates instances, sends them over the wire, another one consumes them. In the end, coupling is inevitable, you only have to choose where it happens.

Comment: whether you want to run services in separate executables, or different threads in the same executable is a separate issue from whether you want to have your code in different repos (you want to structure your project so that that's a boring question, which it is). I'd suggest: keeping everything in the same repo, and when you have an obvious division consider separating into separate projects (in the same repo, all managed by stack) if you have a good justification (e.g. to be able to version dependencies differently) beyond some fuzzy notion of architectural aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm spitting into the wind here, but since.

1. these are *your* types for *your* microservices in *your* project;
2. you want to separate instances from the type definitions only as a mechanism to separate concerns and not to "open" the type definition to random instances defined all over the place;
3. you presumably aren't planning to release this as a general-purpose library for others where some miscreant would define an incompatible `Store` instance on one of your types;

then it seems reasonable to assume that your orphan instances -- despite being orphans -- can reasonably be taken as globally unique instances defined for those type/class combinations.  So, this would be a justified use, if ever there was one, of `-fno-warn-orphans`.

The alternatives you mention for avoiding orphans (newtype wrappers and per-microservice type definitions) sound tiresome and error-prone, respectively, so much so that it seems preferable to keep the instances with the types despite the unnecessary dependencies.